# Node Express Server Cannot GET “/”

Tags: javascript, express, get

```
const https = require("http");
const app= require('./app');

const port =  8080;

const server = https.createServer(app);

server.listen(port)
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] - without the app, it's uncear why you thought you *could* GET `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of what you were trying to do but you can use express in this way:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  /// do something here
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Also, check express guide : http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html